# Error with FOR LOOP in BAT FILE (WINDOWS)

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

Here is a for loop in a bat file, this loop takes numbers 1 through 100 and uses the mod operator on each integer. Im having difficulty calculating the average after the loop ends? can someone help me out with this? I have tried these statement:

```
echo VAR / 100

echo !VAR! / 100

SET /A TOTAL=%VAR% / 100
```

none work.

the following is the current code i have:

```
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (

 SET /A VAR=%%i %% 5 

 SET /A TOTAL=%VAR% / 100

 echo !VAR! 

 echo !TOTAL!

 echo. >> results.txt
```

Comment: Where the loop ends?  The ending bracket isn't there. And your formula looks odd, as total is always 0

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SET /A TOTAL=!VAR! / 100
```

!var! returns the RUN-TIME value of `var`. %var% returns the PARSE-TIME value (ie. BEFORE the statement was executed)

(provided, of course, that you've already executed a

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

instruction)

Comment: You don't need delayed expansion here. `Set /a total=var / 100` works too

Comment: Im not sure if its working correctly, its just returning a bunch of zeros. Here is the code im using to append to results to a text file.SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /L %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
 SET /A VAR=%%i %% 5 
 SET /A TOTAL=!VAR! / 100 
 echo !VAR! 
 echo !TOTAL! 
 echo. >> results.txt
 echo the mod operation is: !VAR! >> results.txt
 echo. >> results.txt

Comment: Well, it's doing precisely what you told it to do. Computers are like that. The point is that you're assigning the numbers (1..100 mod 5) in turn to `var` - this will be 1,2,3,4,0 repeated. You are then calculating `TOTAL` as `var` / 100 - which will be er, (gets calculator...) um - ZERO! What you probably should be doing is accumulating the values of `var` into `total` and THEN dividing by 100 after the loop has finished.